# ANOVA vs other variable selection methods

Tags: regression, anova, feature-selection

ANOVA is introduced in several different contexts as a solution to a variety of problems that apparently do not have much in common, e.g. as a [test for difference between group means](https://brownmath.com/stat/anova1.htm), or as a [predictor selection criterion in linear regression models](https://www.jmp.com/en_in/statistics-knowledge-portal/what-is-multiple-regression/variable-selection.html). As far as I understand, all these different situations can be considered as special cases of a comparison criterion for nested linear models. Please allow me first to explain what ANOVA is according to my understanding before asking my question (which might make no sense if my understanding is wrong).

### My understanding of ANOVA

ANOVA compares two *nested* linear models, i.e., a *full* model and a *partial* model, where the set of predictors in the full model is a superset of the predictors in the partial model. The null hypothesis is that the coefficients of all predictors added in the full model are simultaneously zero. The alternative is that *any* of the coefficients is non-zero, which is not very specific, but the advantage is that no correction for multiple testing is necessary (as long as [not more than *two* models are compared](https://doi.org/10.3758/s13423-015-0913-5)).

This is particularly useful, if a categorial variable ("factor" in R lingo) is added in the full model, because categorial predictors are encoded as $c-1$ dummy variables, where $c$ is the number of categories ("factor levels"), thereby leading to $c-1$ different intercepts depending on their values. A factor is thus useful as a predictor, if any of these intercepts is different from zero, which can be tested with ANOVA.

When ANOVA is applied in practice, it actually becomes a variable selection method: if the full model is significantly different (null hypothesis rejected), the variable/s added by the full model is/are considered useful for prediction. Statistic textbooks generally recommend to test *every* predictor for significance, and the R function `anova.lm` does this sequentially by adding variables one-by-one.

Apart from the usual caveat that this requires a correction for multiple tests like [sequential Bonferroni correction](https://doi.org/10.3758/s13423-015-0913-5), it seems to me that a fundamental problem with this approach is that it is an inherently stepwise approach (the models must be nested) and the result depends on the order in which variables are added.

### My question

As the eventual goal of using ANOVA is variable selection, I wonder: What are the advantages of ANOVA compared to other variable selection methods like all-subset AIC or Lasso regression?

Comment: [This is, ultimately, a stepwise procedure, which has issues.](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/stepwise-regression-problems/)

Comment: @dave This list of objections is interesting. Some seem to be motivated by the frustration that, recently, automated machine learning methods have started to outperform statistical methods tediuously developed over many decases. I do not consider the concerns about p-value and type I error mismatch to be of that relevance in the context of variable selection. Coment 2 by Judd and McClelland is in favour of all-subset selection. A serious objection to ANOVA based approaches seems to be its problem (which precisely?) with redundant predictors. Do Lasso or AIC suffer from the same problem?

Comment: Frank Harrell has discussed on here and on his Twitter how LASSO is unstable. The gist is that, if you bootstrap your LASSO regression, you will find the selected variables to be unstable, so it is not quite picking the “right” variables, just ones that happen to work (overfitting risk).

Comment: @dave Does this mean that LASSO at random picks a representant from a collinear predictor group? Or does this problem also occur with independent predictors?